# WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred Apache Ignite

Tags: java, ignite, java.util.concurrent

I use apache ignite: Ignite ignite = Ignition.start()
But it returns an error:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2 (file:/C:/Users/user/Downloads/apache-ignite-2.8.1-bin/libs/ignite-core-2.8.1.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "main" class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to create Ignite component (consider adding ignite-spring module to classpath) [component=SPRING, cls=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:1067)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:306)
    at IgniteTest.main(IgniteTest.java:11)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to create Ignite component (consider adding ignite-spring module to classpath) [component=SPRING, cls=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.componentException(IgniteComponentType.java:319)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.create0(IgniteComponentType.java:295)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.create(IgniteComponentType.java:208)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:708)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:911)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:820)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:545)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:525)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:303)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.create0(IgniteComponentType.java:281)
    ... 8 more
```

Why do I get this error and how ca I fix it. I have JDK 14
I tried adding in: Run As -> Run Configurations -> Arguments -> VM ->

```
--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
```

But the errors doesn't disappear

Comment: `consider adding ignite-spring module to classpath` Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `ignite-spring` module with dependencies to your classpath to read XML configurations. Cited warning is not related to this.